# How to align controls in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: css

I am just learning ASP.NET MVC 4 and getting unfamiliar with control placement and design form. Actually i don't like to create the default way of placement of controls in my view. I need to have a group of controls into divisions in which it look great. How do i achieve this please guide me. I need something like below...

[image]

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is being asked here. Why don't you just use the WYSIWYG of VS .Net and drag the controls the way you want them. Then it will generate the CSS for you. Then you just need to pretty the CSS up

Comment: I would create 6 divs then place them in that order.

Answer (score 1):

My best recommendation would be to look at something like **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** and using the **[horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)** CSS and markup.

Using something like Bootstrap is going to allow you to concentrate on writing your application and less time on fiddling with CSS, at least initially. Obviously, if your intention is to fiddle with the CSS then please disregard my answer. However, based on the fact that you are just learning ASP.NET MVC 4, there is a lot of functionality to learn as well as how the application is going to look.

Once you feel comfortable with the techniques involved, you can start to modify/remove the Bootstrap CSS to better suit your needs.